A small board-puzzle
Place pieces (red) on the board, so every piece is adjacent to 4, 5 or 6 other pieces.

I've created this puzzle myself playing around with cellular automatons.

Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Adjacent includes diagonally?

Nice puzzle! Simple yet not trivial to solve.

@quarague including diagonal (otherwise 5 or 6 neighbors weren't possible).

A symmetric solution (with pieces represented by Os):

  X O O X X
 O O O O X
 O O X O O
 X O O O O
 X X O O X


Welcome to PSE (Puzzling Stack Exchange)!

Thanks, @WillOctagonGibson!

Why the accepted solution is unique:

 No corner can have a piece in it, because corners are only next to three squares.
 Corollary: As a consequence, every piece next to a corner (like the starting piece) must be next to a piece in every non-corner neighbor. In particular, it forces this configuration:
_ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _
_ _ X O O
_ _ O O O
_ _ O O X

I could proceed with some case-bashing, but instead I'll ask:

 How many pieces can be on an edge?
 An isolated piece can't, because it only has three non-edge neighbors, but three on an edge is also impossible, because it forces this configuration via Corollary:
_ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _
O O _ O O
O O 7 O O
X O O O X
 This means that every edge must have a domino on it (or nothing at all, but any shape fitting in a 4-wide box is impossible by a variation of the above)

How can this be arranged?

 Dominoes automatically form pairs by the Corollary, so we have this:
X O O X X
O O O _ X
O O X O O
X _ O O O
X X O O X
 Both unknown squares must have pieces to satisfy the edge cells, yielding the accepted solution.

